# Is there best way to build this query with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm facing a performance issue on PyMongo, i just need to create a query to find one specific data over the document to solve this issue:

My DATABASE have this SCHEMA:

```
{
    '_id': '123',
    'stock': 'ABC',
    'qrtly_result': {
        '30/09/2020': {
            'link': 'http://www.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

I can easily using find over ID then loop over the result and get what i need it, like this:

```
from db_process import connect_db
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Connect @ DB
client = MongoClient(connect_db.uri)
db = client.get_database(connect_db.data_base)
collection = db[connect_db.collection]

query = collection.find({'_id': '123'})

for x in query:
    item = x.get('qrtly_result').get('30/09/2020').get('link')
    print(item)

>>> http://www.google.com
```

But I'm trying figure out if exist a best way to do this QUERY, because i need to loop over this items thousand times to validate if exist or not.

Comment: you need to create / ask to create secondary indexes on qrtly_result.date

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Your filter is on an `_id` field which is always indexed and unique; it will only ever return one record. Where can you have a performance issue?

Comment: Since you filter on the id, query can't be a list of thousand elements. If you have lots of items in `qrtly_result`. You may consider saving them in another collection. And will only need one query to check if `'30/09/2020'` exists